# ResourceException while deleting an IFile

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have this strange problem in my eclipse plugin project. The code is working fine on Mac, but when I run on Windows, I get this `ResourceException`

```
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
```

And after a long stack trace, it shows at the end:

```
Contains: Could not delete 'C:\Users\.....'
```

The corresponding code is quite simple, I just need to clean a folder and put new things inside.

```
for (IResource res : mfolder.members(IContainer.INCLUDE_PHANTOMS | IContainer.INCLUDE_HIDDEN  IContainer.INCLUDE_TEAM_PRIVATE_MEMBERS)) {
  res.delete(true, null);
}
```

I don't understand why I get a problem only on Windows. The to be deleted file is a config file, all I did with it is to load its contents to a properties object using `props.load(gzCfg.getContents());`. 
So does anyone have an idea what would be the problem?

Edit: stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered while deleting files.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.delete(LocalFile.java:131)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:304)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFile(ResourceTree.java:785)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1979)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:803)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:769)
at my.ui.projects.MyProjectSupport.writePropertiesToFile(MyProjectSupport.java:676)
at my.ui.creation.NewModuleWizard.performFinish(NewModuleWizard.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
at de.dfki.lt.sprout.ui.handler.InitiateModule.execute(InitiateModule.java:122)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Contains: Could not delete: C:\Users\re01\runtime-EclipseApplication\xzz\Module\config.cfg.
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace

Comment: I have edited the post and added the trace.

Comment: The Java `File.delete` method if returning false when Eclipse tries to delete the file.

Comment: I didn't call `File.delete`, but still, why is this exception only shown in Windows?

Comment: Eclipse calls `File.delete` as a result of your `IResource.delete` call. Unfortunately `File.delete` does not give a reason for the failure.